# Python, Chrome - Xpath is Unable to Locate Element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have this HTML and try to parse Barcode

```
</div>
<div class="bc">
<div class="pititle">
   <h2 itemprop="name">Bath Shelf - 5 Pack</h2>
</div>
<div class="brandmanu model">
   <h5>Product code</h5>
   <h6>BA0576</h6>
</div>
<div class="brandmanu gtin">
   <h5>Barcode</h5>
   <h6>5056170307192</h6>
</div>
<div class="brandmanu inner">
   <h5>Inner Barcode</h5>
   <h6>NO INNER</h6>
</div>
<div class="brandmanu outer">
   <h5>Outer barcode</h5>
   <h6>25056170307196</h6>
</div>
<div class="brandmanu brand" itemprop="brand" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand">
```

I try to write this code, but don't get the result:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("brandmanu gtin")
tag_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='brandmanu gtin']")
print(element)
print(tag_list)
```

For `find_element_by_class_name` I get the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".brandmanu gtin"}
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)
```

Please, advise, how to fix code.

Comment: You can't use `find_element_by_class_name` with multiple class names

Comment: @IainShelvington Please clarify. In my understanding, I only use one class name - "brandmanu gtin"

Comment: That is 2 class names, class names are separated by spaces

Comment: @IainShelvington thanks! Are there any ways to deal with this?

Comment: Using xpath should work? Your query seems like it is pretty much there

Comment: @IainShelvington I get only this: "[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="de047b9ed2ac3ac13367a3f310136e3b", element="7aaf87c0-4bb8-4a66-9d1c-cf96d20f042b")>]"

Comment: I get only this: "[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (...)>]" -- looks like you got a match. Do you not know what to do with the results then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get it by `css` selector:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".brandmanu.gtin>h5").text
```

To get the value use:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".brandmanu.gtin>h6").text
```

Dot is used for classes.

If you prefer `xpath`:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="brandmanu gtin"]/h5').text
```

Comment: It does not give an error, but for some reason I get the following result: "<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="2737005b344ae092288f106a18d8492e", element="2abb898f-ae1b-4f66-83b2-a901c5c14a42")>"

Comment: put .text after locator. Check updated answer

Comment: I understood the problem. 1 min